# Click on button to change image using "addEventListener

Tags: javascript

what I am trying to achieve is when I click the div with id="black"
        the image changes from one image to another. But I don't know what
        to do

```js
var image = document.getElementById("change");
var black = document.getElementById("black");

black.addEventListener("click", changeBlack());

function changeBlack() {
  if (image.src == "img/backpack.jpeg") {
    image.src = "img/back.jpeg";
  } else {
    image.src = "img/backpack.jpeg";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <img class="product__img" src="img/backpack.jpeg" alt="images" id="change">
  <h2 class="heading-2">Hugger 30L</h2>
  <p class="paragraph">Smart carry-on backpack</p>
  <h4 class="text-price">Kr 1599</h4>

  <div class="product__colors">
    <div class="product__colors--black " id="black"></div>
    <div class="product__colors--white"></div>
    <div class="product__colors--green"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't stated your problem, but looking at your code, `addEventListener`'s second parameter should be a function, but you're passing the return of a function. Replace `changeBlack()` with `changeBlack`

Answer (score 0):

You should remove parentheses `()`, will be :

```
black.addEventListener("click", changeBlack );
```

Instead of :

```
black.addEventListener("click", changeBlack() );
___________________________________________^^
```

Answer (score 0):

I would declare image inside the function.

```
function changeBlack()
{
    var image = document.getElementById("change");
    if (image.src == "img/backpack.jpeg")
    {
        image.src = "img/back.jpeg";
    }
    else
    {
        image.src = "img/backpack.jpeg";
    }
}
```